# What do each of the actions increase, numerically?

Tags: stack-egg

There are several options available as your site progresses towards winning the internet:

- Ask
- Answer
- Upvote
- Downvote
- Flag
- Nothing
- Restart

Besides the Restart action (self-explanatory), what exactly are the results of each action?

So far I think I've got the following:

- Ask

  - +❤ Question
- Answer

  - +❤ Answer
- Upvote

  - +❤ Users
- Downvote

  - +❤ Quality
  - -❤ Users
- Flag

  - if (Q/A/U/Qual ❤ = 0, +1)
- Nothing

  - ze goggles
- Restart

  - Restarts progress back to A51.

Is this more or less correct?

Comment: @Lohoris That's why I asked the question?

Comment: The precise answers [are on Github now](https://github.com/StackExchange/stackegg).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following have been determined experimentally.

We have four primary indicators: Questions, Answers, Users, and Quality.

Every day, apply a *decay point* to each indicator. If an indicator has any hearts, and it reaches two decay points, remove a heart and clear the decay point. If it has no hearts, and it reaches three decay points, it now becomes red. If it has no hearts and reaches eight decay points, a flag MUST be used or the game is over. (If you have no flags then it's an automatic game over.)

Each indicator has an associated action. Ask with Questions, Answer with Answers, Upvote with Users, and Downvote with Quality. Taking an associated action will clear the decay points, add a single heart, and protect the indicator from a single decay point.

Taking the associated action when an indicator is already at four hearts applies a *buff point*. A single buff point will protect against two decay points, but does not factor into site progress or indicator interactions. (This means that the chosen indicator will resist three days of decay before dropping by a heart.)

(Interactions between indicators, as well as the effects of Downvote, Close, and Flag forthcoming.)

Comment: Ah, I forgot I have an assignment to do... I guess they won't be here quite as quickly as I'd like.

Comment: Does taking the action when the indicator is at 7 decay points reset it to 0? That would seem to make that the highest decay points/action ratio (and the most risky).

Comment: @immibis That's what it looks like. In other words, a red indicator can be ignored for four days before it HAS to be taken care of. You can try this out on a fresh instance, but note that for some reason, Answers seems to start out with two decay points.

Comment: So, after the site is launched and you're trying to win the internets, I noticed that towards the last half of the phase, almost any action that wasn't downvote or close would cost a heart on quality. So at some point, it seems that non-quality actions end up generating 2 decay points. Also around this time, users more or less stop decaying (in fact, I lost a heart on user when downvoting, but gained it back by asking a question). So at some point, the game evolves and these rules/guidelines are no longer accurate.

Comment: @Ellesedil I think these may have more to do with interactions between indicators. For example, Users probably seems like it stops decaying because Traffic gives it enough of a boost to stop decay. Also, I suspect Traffic also decreases Quality. However, it's a little bit too hard for me to get to Launched by myself and test, so I've CWed the post -- feel free to edit it in if you figure it out!

Comment: Actually, one "decay point" decreases a value by exactly 0.3

Answer (score 4):

You've got it almost correct; the only difference is that Downvote decreases Users by exactly 0.5. Also, it should be noted that there is another action that appears after graduation: Close. Close does -2 to Questions and +2 to Quality.

Comment: And Close may very well be a **trap** if you're interested in keeping questions high.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that the other posts seemed failed to mention: The decay point reset by voting and decaying aren't equal. It will usually take 2 turns to decay after increasing that stat, but takes 3 turns after it is previously decayed.

Instead of a "decay point", I suspect the stat is not an integer internally, and is rounded when displayed. Each time increasing the stat by voting, it goes to the greater integer than the rounded value. And for each turn, the stats are decreased by somewhere between 0.3 and 1/3 hearts. But the stats also affect each other and I don't know the exact formula. (Constantly decreasing 1/3 * 4 hearts also makes winning impossible, so it cannot be strictly following this.)

So if a state is not full, left alone one turn after last vote, or two turns after last decay, and increasing it will give you 4/3 hearts. The next optimal options are voting what is just voted, or one turn after decay, which is 1 heart. Voting full stats is probably never optimal by this calculation, but I'm not really sure. Also be careful not to let two stats fall into the 4/3 hearts optimal state together, or one of them will decay.

The turns you can ignore warnings seemed decreasing during each period. And the affection of a low question stat to the answers is increasing. I'm not sure whether it is because the stats are once greater, or this still happens if you mostly do nothing, or it is because you have a fixed number of chances ignoring warnings and the affection of questions has a delay. But unless you did something bad deliberately, I think it is pretty safe to ignore them. That is: after the grace period is below 4 days (except downvoting decreases user's by probably less than a day, which is effectively still one day), you won't get any more warnings. And questions never have an visible effect on answers if you are following the right strategy.

Comment: My guess about the decay is mostly inspired by the final line in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/279180), and I thought they will do something similar. And it turned out to be true. [an 232 day bot (with obvious bug in private beta) for whoever still interested](http://pastebin.com/N5A74eEM).